# Exibir variável somente uma vez em um foreach e contar total de linhas de um IF

Tags: php, foreach, count

Tenho um script, que basicamente, compara os arquivos de uma table do banco com os arquivos de um diretório, e ele *mostra os arquivos que NÃO estão no banco de dados e estão no diretório*.

**Tenho 2 problemas**:

1. Contar a quantidade de arquivos que **não** estão no banco e estão no diretório
2. Exibir mensagem com essa quantidade, somente uma vez dentro do `foreach`

---

### Código que estou utilizando:

```
    <?php
    include('menu.php'); include('connect.php'); 

    $files = glob("teste-uploads/*.{pdf,jpg,png}", GLOB_BRACE);  // Encontra nomes dos arquivos de determinada pasta e salva no array $files

    $Busca_Imagens = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT fotos FROM teste");  // Busca nome das imagens no seu Banco de Dados

    while($Checa_Imagens = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Busca_Imagens)){

    $images[] = 'teste-uploads/' . $Checa_Imagens['fotos'];
          };

    foreach($files as $file){
    if(!in_array($file, $images)){

    echo "Cerca de <b>" .count($file). "</b> arquivo(s) que não estão no banco de dados <p></p>"; // Número total

    echo "<b>" . $file . "</b><br>"; // Exibe os arquivos
    }}?>
```

[image: PRINT]

> O problema é que não está contando corretamente e a frase "Cerca de ..." está se repetindo a cada arquivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem vários problemas em sua implementação:

1. Não está contando corretamente, pois a cada iteração só tem 1 mesmo;
2. A frase está se repetindo porque ela está dentro do loop;
   Você pode resolver isso colocando a frase em uma variável a ser concatenada, e inicializando um contador fora do loop:

```php
// Encontra nomes dos arquivos de determinada pasta e salva no array $files
$files = glob("teste-uploads/*.{pdf,jpg,png}", GLOB_BRACE);

// Busca nome das imagens no seu Banco de Dados
$Busca_Imagens = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT fotos FROM teste");  

while ($Checa_Imagens = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Busca_Imagens)) {
    $images[] = 'teste-uploads/' . $Checa_Imagens['fotos'];
}
$contador = 0;
$html = '';
foreach ($files as $file) {
  if (!in_array($file, $images)) {
    // Número total
    $contador++;
    $html .= "<b>" . $file . "</b><br>"; 
  }
}
echo 'Cerca de <b>' . $contador . '</b> arquivo(s) que não estão no banco de dados <p></p>';

// Exibe os arquivos
echo $html;
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!

Comment: Tiago, você sabe me dizer se consigo mencionar todas as subpastas de uma pasta de uma vez? na parte `$files = glob("teste-uploads/*.{pdf,jpg,png}", GLOB_BRACE);`

Comment: Tem sim:
`$iterator = new RecursiveTreeIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("teste-uploads/", RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
foreach($iterator as $path) {
  echo $path."<br>";
}`

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o código huahuaha, vou testar aqui. Eu possuo uma pasta chamada `uploads`, nela, tem *12 subpastas*, com os meses do ano... Eu consigo fazer o que mencionei no post, selecionando todas as subpastas de uma vez só, então?

Comment: Sim, caso queira filtrar ainda dá pra melhorar com o `RecursiveRegexIterator`: `$rd = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("teste-uploads/", RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$rr = new RecursiveRegexIterator($rd, '/\.(pdf|jpg|png)$/');
$it = new RecursiveTreeIterator($rr);
foreach($it as $path) {
  echo $path."<br>";
}`

Comment: Claro, só verifique se o formato da vairável `$path` é igual ao que está no banco.

Comment: Mas, como eu faria para referenciar os campos? nessa parte do code: `{
    $images[] = 'teste-uploads/' . $Checa_Imagens['fotos'];
}` , são 12 campos na tabela, os 12 possuem caminho de documentos...